# Как использовать у Bootstrap только Navbar, а остальное убрать?

Tags: css, bootstrap

Я использую Bootstrap только для Navbar. Однако у него есть стили для `<table>`, которые мне не нужны и только перестилизовывают что не надо.

Как использовать стили Bootstrap'а только для Navbar?

Answer (score 0):

В папке `/bootstrap/scss/` лежат компоненты фреймворка, который можно импортировать в свой scss по отдельности.

Например так:

Ваш style.scss

```css
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/navbar';
...
```

Подробнее на [офф сайте](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/customize/sass/#importing).

Comment: Что потом с style.scss делать?